# Conditional statement in R based on multiple rasters

Tags: raster, r, loop, conditional

I have:

- `raster_1`: an integer raster with non-sequential values `i` (101, 130, 240, 323)
- `i`: a watershed discharging X of sediment in the environment
- `raster_2`: represents the water quality for each watershed `i` with values ranging from 0 to 100,000 - named `plume_i`

I have ~400 rasters representing the water quality of 400 watersheds.

I would like to build a loop to set the values in `raster_1` to `NA` for each zone (defined by the values: 101, 130, 240, 323 in `raster_1`) when `raster_2` for the corresponding value (e.g., `plume_101`) is 0, using R.

For instance,

- When `raster_1 = 101 & plume_101 = 0`, assign `NA` to `raster_1` otherwise return `raster_1` values
- When `raster_1 = 130 & plume 130 = 0`, assign `NA` to `raster_1` otherwise return `raster_1` values
- When raster_1 = 240 & plume 240 = 0, assign `NA` to `raster_1` otherwise return `raster_1` values
  and so forth...

How can I do this?

Comment: `plume_101` should only have values where `raster_1` is 101?

Comment: @ElioDiaz yes you are correct and thank you for your answer it was super helpful and i was able to get it work!!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood, you will be overwriting raster_1, putting `NA` when the condition is met. Here, the key is `get` which fetches an object from the environment by a string name.

```r
library(raster)

# we create some rasters with same extent
m = matrix(sample(c(101,130,240,323),100, replace = T), ncol = 10)
r = raster(m)
p_101 = matrix(sample(0:10, 100, replace = T), ncol = 10)
plume_101 = raster(p_101)
p_130 = matrix(sample(0:10, 100, replace = T), ncol = 10)
plume_130 = raster(p_130)
p_240 = matrix(sample(0:10, 100, replace = T), ncol = 10)
plume_240 = raster(p_240)
p_323 = matrix(sample(0:10, 100, replace = T), ncol = 10)
plume_323 = raster(p_323)


par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in c(101,130,240,323)) {
  r[r[] == i & get(sprintf("plume_%s", i))[] == 0] = NA
  plot(r, main = i, col = c("gold", "blue","brown", "tomato", "green"))
}
```

In the plot you may see how subsequently `NA` are added in each iteration
[image]